curl -T golang equivalent to be used in Starrocks
I need to use transcript curl expression to Golang, however when I try to convert
curl --location-trusted -u <username>:<password> -H "label:123" \     -H "Expect:100-continue" \     -H "column_separator:," \     -H "columns: id, name, score" \     -T example1.csv -XPUT \     http://<fe_host>:<fe_http_port>/api/mydatabase/table1/_stream_load
I can't find a proper and canonical way to send -T example1.csv in http.NewRequest()
Can anyone please explain how curl -T file works?
Should I read the contents and pass it as request body?
Should I do it this way ?
file_contents, err := os.ReadFile('example.csv'); if err != nil {   return err      }
r := bytes.NewReader(file_contents)

req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", "http://someURL.com", r)

I tried to send file to starrocks stream loader.

The code in the question correctly passes the file to the request body.  You must also set request headers.
file_contents, err := os.ReadFile('example.csv')
if err != nil { log.Fatal(err)
r := bytes.NewReader(file_contents)

req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", "http://<fe_host>:<fe_http_port>/api/mydatabase/table1/_stream_load", r)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
req.Header.Set("label", "123")
req.Header.Set("Expect", "100-continue")
req.Header.Set("column_separator", ",")
req.Header.Set("columns", "id, name, score")
req.SetBasicAuth("<username>", "<password>")
resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
bodyText, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%s\n%s\n", resp.Status, bodyText)

